My Blender 2.79 can't import OBJ with a name with specific word

I have some obj files that name start with "heart", it were fine before but apparently it just happened a few days ago that I can't import any objects that started with "heart" in the name.
What's the cause of it?

I think it's rather the location of the file than the name of the file that is a problem. It looks like you don't have permission to access this folder. Try launching Blender in admin mode

It looks as if you don't have permission to access that folder according to the error message which isn't anything to do with Blender itself.

that's weird bc that's the folder i always use to saved my most uses files. i'm now trying to move the files to other folder now and seems to fix the issue! (but i still don't know what's wrong with that folder lol)

Wasn't the heart thing a folder itself? You will also get Permission denied if you try to read a directory as if it was a file.
